# Howto disable/hide Navigation-Tab 'Status' in phpMyAdmin4 multi-user environment

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

I need to disable the Navigation-Tab 'Status' in a phpMyAdmin4 multi-user environment. [This post](http://blog.secaserver.com/2012/12/customize-disable-phpmyadmin-export-menu/) explains how to do it but it seems as it is for previous versions of phpMyAdmin.

As explained in the above link there should be a file named 'server_links.inc.php'. Under 'usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/' there does not exist such file... These are my server_* files:

- server_bin_log.lib.php
- server_collations.lib.php
- server_common.inc.php
- server_common.lib.php
- server_databases.lib.php
- server_engines.lib.php
- server_plugins.lib.php
- server_privileges.lib.php
- server_status.lib.php
- server_status_advisor.lib.php
- server_status_monitor.lib.php
- server_status_queries.lib.php
- server_status_variables.lib.php
- server_user_groups.lib.php
- server_users.lib.php
- server_variables.lib.php

In which file is the tab-navigation stored?
How can I disable/hide the 'Status'-Tab?
How can I restrict access for SQL Queries like 'SHOW STATUS' after hiding the 'Status'-Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my working code for hiding the tab 'Status' in /phpmyadmin/libraries/Menu.class.php:

```
if ($is_superuser) {
        $tabs['status']['icon'] = 's_status.png';
        $tabs['status']['link'] = 'server_status.php';
        $tabs['status']['text'] = __('Status');
        $tabs['status']['active'] = in_array(
            basename($GLOBALS['PMA_PHP_SELF']),
            array(
                'server_status.php',
                'server_status_advisor.php',
                'server_status_monitor.php',
                'server_status_queries.php',
                'server_status_variables.php'
            )
        );
    }
```

This is my working code in /phpmyadmin/server_status.php to deny access anyway if not superuser:

```
if (!$GLOBALS['dbi']->isSuperuser()) {
    $msg = PMA_Message::error(__('No Privileges'));
    $msg->display();
    exit;
}
```

Note that the other files belonging to server_status.php should also contain the superuser check, so that no one can access these files directly:
'server_status_advisor.php',
'server_status_monitor.php',
'server_status_queries.php',
'server_status_variables.php'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the menu tabs without touching the code, the user groups feature will do just that; see http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=usergroup#cfg_Servers_usergroups.

You can can also change the code, in libraries/Menu.class.php.

Answer (score 0):

for newest phpmyadmin, you can edit at
`libraries/classes/menu.php`

refer to function `_getMenu()`

```
if (strlen((string) $this->_table) > 0) {
    $tabs = $this->_getTableTabs();
    $url_params['db'] = $this->_db;
    $url_params['table'] = $this->_table;
    $level = 'table';
} elseif (strlen($this->_db) > 0) {
    $tabs = $this->_getDbTabs();
    $url_params['db'] = $this->_db;
    $level = 'db';
} else {
    $tabs = $this->_getServerTabs();
    $level = 'server';
}
```

and then you can modify menu you wanted to, let say edit menu table tabs, then edit function `_getTableTabs`. eg. you wanted to make menu export hide permanently then comment this code bellow

```
$tabs['export']['icon'] = 'b_tblexport';
$tabs['export']['link'] = 'tbl_export.php';
$tabs['export']['args']['single_table'] = 'true';
$tabs['export']['text'] = __('Export');
```

PS. this solution only for permanently hide